# How can I access the model properties from extended attribute when using textboxfor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Conceptually I would like the following code to work:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Something, null, new {
                                @class = "custom",
                                data_min = x.min,
                                data_max = x.max,
                                data_step = x.step 
})
```

Of course it doesn't it seems I can't access the properties `min`, `max` etc from the extended attributes section.

How can I implement this?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be easiest to create an `HtmlHelper` extension, then use that in place of `TextBoxFor`. Could probably get you started if you want to post the model you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `Model`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(
    x => x.Something, 
    new {
        @class = "custom",
        data_min = Model.min,
        data_max = Model.max,
        data_step = Model.step
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to your model

```
public IDictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }
```

Then

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeValue, Model.Attributes)
```